# Django Managers, ModelForms and some confusion

Tags: django, django-forms, dry, business-logic, django-managers

I was planning to write a basic clock-in/clock-out app for worktime tracking using Django. Right now my code works (start/stop a shift or do pauses), but I don't use any ModelForms or ModelManagers. All business code is inside my views and a services.py file, this doesn't seem to be the correct way.

I tried to read into ModelManagers and ModelForms, but I think it just confused the hell out of me.

Let's say I have a model WorkTime:

```
class WorkTime(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    shift_started = models.DateTimeField()
    shift_finished = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    shift_duration = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
    work_reason = models.TextField(null=True)
```

I now want to have two possibilities:

- User can start his shift by visiting a specific View (/clock/start/). Only the starting time is added.
- User visits the stop view (/clock/stop/) to end his current shift, the finishing time added into the corresponding row.
- User adds his shift manually after it was finished, therefore adding the starting and finishing time.

As my code is right now, it's not a real beauty and definitely not DRY. How can I solve the problem the most clever way, like defining ONE ModelForm that fits all possible cases (Just start a new shift, end a running shift (only by accessing views in the browser) or add a whole shift manually with a HTML-form). Or would I split it up into having a ModelManager that does the shift starting/stopping part and a ModelForm for the manual addition of shits as an actual HTML-form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing shift start and stop time simply by entering some URL via normal GET request is not an good idea. Browsers can cache that requests or fire that requests more than one (there is no pop-up when refreshing page that it can perform operation twice, like on POST requests). So you should better change that to POST requests.

For all of that views you can of course use one `ModelForm`:

```
class SiftForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = WorkTime
        fields = ('created_at', 'shift_started', 'shift_finished') # you shouldn't pass user and duration time here



class ShiftStartView(CreateView):
    model = WorkTime
    form_class = ShiftForm
    success_url = "some_url" # after creating WorkTime, view will redirect to that url. You can (and really should) pass reverse_lazy() here, instead of URL as string, if you don't want to hardcode URL.

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # if you want to prevent creating 2 started but not stopped WorkTimes for one user, you should put logic preventing it here.

        return super(ShiftStartView, self).dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        worktime = form.save(commit=False)
        worktime.employee = self.request.user

        worktime.save()
        return super(ShiftStartView, self).form_valid(form)
```

That way you can create also forms for creating `WorkTime` by hand. For creating stop view, you should use `UpdateView` and get current `WorkTime` for user in `get_object` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question: Why would I add 'created_at' to the fields, as it the 'auto_now_add=True' option in the model. Wouldn't this be redundant?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It shouldn't be here.

Comment: I've still not moved any further. For my application I want the user to have two ways of starting his shift.

a) Click on a button, that now submits a form and starts the shift
b) Fill out a form by hand with all data (start and end time)

I thought I could use the same CreateView/ModelForm for this, but I can't manage to overcome the validation process. If the user justs clicks the button, then normally the starting time is not submitted (as one doesn't specify it, the user just clicks a button!). Now I'd like to add the starting_time manually in the view, but I think I'm lost.

Comment: Just solved the problem by defining a "def post:" inside the CreateView-class and copying request.POST, so that it becomes mutable. Then I add the default values (if 'start' in request.POST:, e.g. the "start"-submit button was pressed).

Is this, again, too much logic inside the view?

Comment: No, it's not. But you're not obligated to re-use that view for each action. It's class based view, so you can subclass it and implement different behaviour on different URLs. I'm not saying that you should avoid re-using that view, I just won't do it.

Comment: Thanks. I think my problem is just a conceptual one. What I'd like to have is the following: On the frontpage the logged-in user can click several buttons, and start a different action. I can manage to identify each button by the "if 'action-name' in request.POST" conditional. The problem now is, the form-action redirects every submit-button to the same pages, which will show a specific view. In this case it's the CreateView. But I'd also want to have an UpdateView for a specific action. Therefore I think ModelForms+Class-based Views are the wrong approach here and I need to use normal views?